# Map a javascript object into array structure

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object like this:

```
{"label":["Option 1","Option 2","Option 3"],"share":[0.0650068849312104,0.00873977167120444,0.00873977167120444]}
```

I need to convert this to an array that looks like this:

```
[{label: "Option 1", share: 0.0650068849312104}, {label: "Option 2", share: 0.00873977167120444}, {label: "Option 3", share: 0.00873977167120444}]
```

In other words, it needs to be an array of objects of the same length as the number of data points.

I am very new to javascript, so I apologize if this is a bad question. I haven't been able to find a satisfactory reason elsewhere.  Do I need to use something like object.keys()?  If so, how do I use it?  It's just not clear to me how to convert this into an array and map it into this structure.

Any and all help is appreciated!

**Edit: removing reference to JSON**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 const result = obj.label.map( (label,index) => ({label, share:obj.share[index]}) );
```

Where *obj* is the first code row of your question ( or a reference pointing to it), then result will be the second code row.

Comment: `map` iterates over the entries of the `label` array and creates a new array by calling a function on each element. The `=>` syntax is shorthand for a function that takes argument `label` and `index`, for the entries in the `label` array, and then returns an object in the form requested, using `index` to pluck the matching value from the `share` array. `map` returns the array so-created.

Comment: @jacob youre welcome ;) and its easy to perform magic: its just an *arrow function* with javascripts new object syntax in conjunction with Array.map. Please don't just copy and paste, try to learn from it ;)

Comment: Certainly, the explanation from Karl helps explain how it works as well.  I'll definitely use this strategy for other things in the future.